# Is it possible to determine whose code (according to `git blame`) was affected by each hunk output by `git diff`?

Tags: git

I have a large cross-cutting commit that I would like to split up according to the authors whose code was affected, both to increase the reviewers' familiarity with the code they're reviewing, and to divide the review burden equitably.

I realize that the blame may be mixed within a given hunk, in which case it would be nice to either collect multiple reviewers or just choose the most "blameworthy" one (breaking ties arbitrarily is fine).

Answer (score 6):

Interesting question. I couldn't find any solution simply using git-flags but some quick googling led me to this utility: [git-diff-blame](https://github.com/toddlipcon/tlipcon-bin/blob/master/git-diff-blame). (I did not write the tool)

It displays the actual hunks + the 'blame' line for each line in the hunk.

Comment: This seems to work pretty well, thanks. One note, if you use it yourself: you have to run it from the root of your repository.

Comment: There is now also a [fork of the script](https://github.com/dmnd/git-diff-blame) which overcomes the "root directory only" limitation.